# ChildRoutes config not working anymore

Tags: react-router

So before this config use to work with react-router. But now I got a error message saying that; But I saw you need to use , but how to render the routes config inside`ReactDom.render( < div >
    <Router history = {hashHistory}routes = {routes} > < /Router> </div>,
    document.getElementById('react-app'));`
?

> routes.map is not a function

Can someone help me please.

```
const routes = {
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [{
        path: '/home',
        getComponent: (location, callback) => {
            if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
                callback(null, Home);
            } else {
                callback(null, HomePage);
            }
        }
    },

    {
        path: '/login',
        component: LoginPage
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you show us where you are using `routes`

Comment: Which version are you using ? Which version did you write this for ?

Comment: Before I was using react-router version "^3.0.0" but now I'm using version "^4.2.0" and since then it's not working anymore.